# Using Kindle Preview 3 export, Amazon says the file type is not supported

Tags: kindle, calibre

I converted a `pdf` file to `mobi` using Calibre, then opened the `mobi` file in Kindle Previewer 3. I have exported the file to desktop, and sent it to my Amazon Kindle email account.
But I got the following reply:

```
* xxxx.mobi

The Kindle Personal Document Service can convert and deliver the following types of documents:
Microsoft Word (.doc, .docx)
Rich Text Format (.rtf)
HTML (.htm, .html) 
Text (.txt) documents
Archived documents (zip , x-zip) and compressed archived documents
Mobi book
```

How to get the Kindle app for Android to show the book's cover?

Comment: I tried to format and clean up your question a bit. I am not sure if "t mobi" is something real, or that the 't' was the cat on the keyboard.